# Wait for openParentApplication callback to complete

Tags: swift, concurrency, watchkit

My watch app uses openParentApplication to request data from its WatchKit extension. It starts with the watch app's home page init():

```
class HomePage : WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: WKInterfaceTable!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        NSLog("Starting home page.")

        Fetcher.GetData()         // Get data from WatchKit extension

        NSLog("Got data!")
        // Create table rows using GetData() return values
        self.table.setRowTypes(rowTypes)
        // etc...
    }

}

class Fetcher : NSObject {
    // Request data from WatchKit extension:
    class func GetData() {
        NSLog("GetData() begins.")
        WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(
            ["command" : "sendData"],
            reply: {
                (returnedValues, error) -> Void in
                    GotData(returnedValues, error)
            }
        )
        NSLog("GetData() ends.")
    }

    // Callback for openParentApplication in GetData():
    class func GotData(dict: [String:AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) {
        NSLog("GotData() starts.")
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Error in GotData(): %@", error!.debugDescription)
        }
        NSLog("GotData() processing...")

        // use the data returned in dict...

        NSLog("GotData() done.")
    }

}
```

The extension fills an appropriate dictionary and calls reply() before returning.  It takes a second or so to prep and return the data.

Here's the problem:
Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  Sometimes the home page receives the data perfectly.  Sometimes the callback, GotData(), is not called.  When it works right:

```
21:00:46.151 WatchKit Extension: Starting home page.
21:00:46.171 WatchKit Extension: GetData() begins.
21:00:46.180 WatchKit Extension: GotData() starts.
21:00:47.175 WatchKit Extension: GotData() done.
21:00:47.177 WatchKit Extension: GetData() ends.
21:00:47.188 WatchKit Extension: Got data!
```

When it doesn't:

```
21:00:46.151 WatchKit Extension: Starting home page.
21:00:46.171 WatchKit Extension: GetData() begins.
21:00:46.177 WatchKit Extension: GetData() ends.
21:00:46.188 WatchKit Extension: Got data!
```

I found out: if the home page does things in willActivate() then the GotData() callback never runs.  That is not the only failure case, however.

How can I ensure that the callback actually executes?  I suspect that dispatch_groups are at least part of the answer, but I don't know enough to put them together correctly.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your table once the `GotData` method finishes processing the reply. The `Fetcher.GetData()` call is asynchronous and is not blocking. Therefore, the code in the rest of the `init` function needs to be moved inside a callback (or closure). Here's a modified version of your logic that handles the async behavior correctly.

```
class HomePage : WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: WKInterfaceTable!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        NSLog("Starting home page.")

        Fetcher.GetData { dataValues in
            NSLog("Got data!")
            // Create table rows using GetData() return values
            self.table.setRowTypes(rowTypes)
            // etc...
        }
    }
}

class Fetcher : NSObject {
    // Request data from WatchKit extension:
    class func GetData(completionHandler: ([String: String]) -> Void) {
        NSLog("GetData() begins.")
        WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(
            ["command" : "sendData"],
            reply: {
                (returnedValues, error) -> Void in
                GotData(returnedValues, error)
            }
        )
        NSLog("GetData() ends.")
    }

    // Callback for openParentApplication in GetData():
    class func GotData(dict: [String:AnyObject]?, error: NSError?, completionHandler: ([String: String]) -> Void) {
        NSLog("GotData() starts.")
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Error in GotData(): %@", error!.debugDescription)
        }
        NSLog("GotData() processing...")

        // use the data returned in dict...

        let data = ["someKey": "someValue"]

        completionHandler(data)

        NSLog("GotData() done.")
    }
}
```

Hopefully that gets you going in the right direction.